# Android: Get the clicked url that opened the application

Tags: android, android-activity, deep-linking, activity-lifecycle, applinks

I have App Links setup which routes the specific urls into the application.
How can I determine what the url of the last clicked url that opened the app was?

The issue I'm running into is if multiple listeners for onResume are registered (IE I open the app from different sources a url click from Safari and messages), I get all of the previously clicked urls called.

```
public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
    String currentLink = activity.getIntent().getDataString();
}
```

Essentially I'm looking for the Android equivalent of the following iOS code to get the url which opened up the app.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray * _Nullable))restorationHandler {
    NSURL *clickedURL = userActivity.webpageURL;
}
```

Comment: URLs do not "open" the "app". They start activities. There is no concept in Android of "the last clicked url that opened the app". "I get all of the previously clicked urls called" -- so, keep track of the most recent of those.

Comment: What you asking is how to use deep linking in Android. :)
Check this example: https://medium.com/@ageitgey/everything-you-need-to-know-about-implementing-ios-and-android-mobile-deep-linking-f4348b265b49

Comment: Would overriding onNewIntent(Intent) be helpful in your situation? That method can deliver the new Intent to the Activity *even if the Activity is already on the top of the activity stack*: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)